# why can index be larger either the trace goes smaller or larger in index $\ge 4$ case?

Tags: von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

I am studying the index of subfactor and basic construction recently. Suppose $M=\mathcal{R}$ to be the infinite hyperfinite II1 factor. For projection $p\in \mathcal{R}$, $p\mathcal{R}p$ is also a hyperfinite II1 factor. Note that all the infinite hyperfinite II1 factors are isomorphic, let $\theta:p\mathcal{R}p\to (1-p)\mathcal{R}(1-p)$ be the isomorphism. Let $N=\{x+\theta(x)|x\in p\mathcal{R}p\}$ to be a subfactor with $p\in M\cap N'$. Since $pMp=Np$ and $(1-p)M(1-p)=N(1-p)$, $M\cap N'=\text{span}\{p,1-p\}$, we have 
\begin{align*}
[M:N]&=\frac{1}{\text{tr}_M(p)}[pMp:Np]+\frac{1}{\text{tr}_M(1-p)}[(1-p)M(1-p):N(1-p)]\\&=\frac{1}{\text{tr}_M(p)}+\frac{1}{1-\text{tr}_M(p)}.
\end{align*}
So when $\text{tr}_M(p)=\frac{1}{2}$, the index $[M:N]$ reaches its minimal 4. But I am wondering why either $\text{tr}_M(p)$ goes smaller or larger can make the index larger. Because for any $p$, we can always find a $\theta$ to be isomorphic.

Comment: Hi Quan Chen, I am not sure to understand your question, but note that for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1-x}$, we have $f(]0,1[) = [4,\infty[$.

Comment: When I learned the orthonormal basis of $M$ over $N$, the index $[M:N]$ is related to the number of elements. But from the example above, I cannot see why $\text{tr}_M(p)$ can influence the $[M:N]$.

Comment: The notion of basis of a vector space over a field, extends to the notion of Pimsner-Popa basis of $M$ over $N$, but the index $[M:N]$ is not necessarily an integer, so that is not necessarily the cardinal of the basis. There is a typo in your definition of $N$, it should be $N=\{x+\theta(x)|x\in p\mathcal{R}p\}$. With this correct definition, you can see $N$ as composed of two blocks whose size vary with $\text{tr}_M(p)$, and then $[M:N]$ varies with $\text{tr}_M(p)$ by the formula you wrote. You should read the book *Introduction to Subfactors* by V. Jones and V.S. Sunder.